# using ip address component C#

Tags: c#, ip-address, ip, custom-component

I am trying to use a component which named as A C# IP Address Control but it has a problem I think. because when I increase its value 1, it gives me some wrong result. forexample

```
ipAddressControl3.Text = "192.168.1.25";
IPAddress ipAddress1 = new IPAddress(ipAddressControl3.GetAddressBytes());
ipAddress1.Address++;
MessageBox.Show(ipAddress1.ToString());
```

returns : "193.168.1.25" ! but I expect "192.168.1.26"

what is the problem ?

here is the components link : [A C# IP Address Control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/IpAddrCtrlLib.aspx)

edit : Maybe solution like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217980/c-little-endian-or-big-endian)  but I couldnt implemented it..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use IPAddress and IPv4Mask to obtain IP address range?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/996848/how-to-use-ipaddress-and-ipv4mask-to-obtain-ip-address-range)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I convert my ip big endian to little like this :

```
int ipaddress= IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(BitConverter.ToInt32(IPAddress.Parse(ipAddressControl3.Text).GetAddressBytes(), 0));
```

and it work.

Answer (score 1):

IP address are stored in network byte order (big-endian), whereas integers on Intel platforms are little-endian.

Comment: Hmm I see, soo what is the solution ?

Comment: Well, a quick hack to increment only the last octet is to replace `++` with `+= 0x1 << 24`.

Comment: I tried it but in this situaton it fails..

ıpAddressControl3.Text = "0.0.0.255";
IPAddress ipAddress1 = new IPAddress(ıpAddressControl3.GetAddressBytes());
ipAddress1.Address += 0x1 << 24;
MessageBox.Show(ipAddress1.ToString());

resunt is : 0.0.0.0

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I said - "a quick hack to increment *only* the last octet".

Comment: if so can I convert the value (big-endian) to (little-endian) or antipodean and increase 0.0.0.255 to 0.0.1.0 ?

Comment: Yes. That would work. Once the value is in little-endian, then you could just increment it using `++` and it would work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ipAddressControl3.Text = "192.168.1.25";

byte[] ip = ipAddressControl3.GetAddressBytes();
ip[3] = (byte) (++ip[3]);

IPAddress ipAddress1 = new IPAddress(ip);
MessageBox.Show(ipAddress1.ToString());
```

Comment: unfortunately it gives 0.0.0.0 result for 0.0.0.255
I expect it have to be 0.0.1.0